# Hibernate search @IndexEmbedded combines collection in one field

Tags: lucene, full-text-search, hibernate-search

I have mapping which looks like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_documents")
@Indexed(interceptor = DocumentIndexingInterceptor.class)
public class Document implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @DocumentId
    private Long id;

    @IndexedEmbedded(prefix = "sections.", indexNullAs = "null", 
      includePaths = {"body"})
    private List<Section> sections;

//...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "t_sections")
@Indexed
public class Section implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @DocumentId
    private Long id;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ndocumentid")
    private Document document;

    @Field(name = "body", 
           analyze = Analyze.YES, 
           index = Index.YES, 
           store = Store.NO,
           norms = Norms.NO)
    @Column(name = "vbody")
    private String body;

//...
}
```

Now if I have an entity Document with two Section entities looking like:
Section 1 body: "Answer your own question";
Section 2 body: "Post Your Question";
*Other values are just not important.
When I look indexed entity Document in Luke **sections.body** looks like:

```
answer your own question post your question
```

When I search documents containing sentence "answer post" it would find this particular document. Which is not my desired result. I want this document to be found only if my searched string found within single body.

Is this even possible? If not, is there any way to achieve what I want.

Answer (score 0):

This is an intrinsic limitation of `@IndexedEmbedded` on a collection: all elements of the collections are merged together.

First question to ask yourself is: are you really searching for documents? If you don't want two words in different sections to match, it is likely that you want to search for sections instead.
If it is the case, you may simply change your query to target `Section.class` instead of `Document.class`.

---

*If* you need to be able to search for fields in `Document` too, then you can do embedding the other way round: put an `@IndexedEmbedded` on `Section.document`, like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_documents")
@Indexed(interceptor = DocumentIndexingInterceptor.class)
public class Document implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @DocumentId
    private Long id;

    @ContainedIn // IMPORTANT: this will ensure that the "section" index is updated whenever a section is updated
    private List<Section> sections;

//...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "t_sections")
@Indexed // TODO: if you need it, put an interceptor here, just as in Document?
public class Section implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @DocumentId
    private Long id;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ndocumentid")
    @IndexedEmbedded(indexNullAs = "null", includePaths = { /* LIST YOUR PATHS HERE */ })
    private Document document;

    @Field(name = "body", 
           analyze = Analyze.YES, 
           index = Index.YES, 
           store = Store.NO,
           norms = Norms.NO)
    @Column(name = "vbody")
    private String body;

//...
}
```

Comment: Document is my main entity. It contains a LOT of fields like title, status, author, dates, etc. All of them are indexed and searched.
as a result I want to get query like `get me documents where title equal to "some title" and any of sections contains word "some words"`

Comment: @JohnSmith Ok. If you don't feel like listing the included paths explicitly, you can just omit them: all fields will be included. Then the query you gave would translate as `document.title:"some title" body:"some words"` if you queried the section index instead of the document index.